# had seemed to adapt/seemed to have adapted

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

are these two sentences both correct? Is it idiomatic to express the exactly same idea in two ways? In my opinion it doesn't matter whether I choose to use either *past perfect + simple infinitve* or *past simple + past infinitive*.

(preceding text in the past tense)

**A**

- He **had (always) seemed to adapt** to any kind of situation very well and that time it was no different.

**B**

- **He (always) seemed to have adapted** to any kind of situation very well and that time it was no different.

To me, there seems to be only a stylistic difference.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: You don't need a perfect verb form at all! Just *He [always] seemed to adapt to any kind of situation...* is fine. Come to that, do you *really* think including ***seemed*** makes sense here? Unless you specifically want to imply that his adaptation was ***in appearance only** (not "real")*, that's just pointless extra verbiage as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding past perfect and past simple tense](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/34829/understanding-past-perfect-and-past-simple-tense)

Comment: This question has been asked and answered numerous times.

Comment: I don't think this question has even been posted here. The fact that it is related to the past simple/past perfect issue doesn't make it similar to the other threads I've seen here. It differs.

Comment: @PeterJennings That question doesn't mention any perfect-aspect infinitives, which are a major focus of this question ("to have adapted"). Perhaps there's another question that this one duplicates more closely?

Answer (score 2):

I see a slight difference between the two sentences, which hardly affects the overall meaning.

**A** On every previous occasion he had seemed (at the time) to adapt well.

**B** Looking back, it seemed to the narrator that he had adapted well every time.